# php - preg_match issue with empty form fields on update query

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

The following flags an error if a form field is empty and also flags an error if anything other than letters are entered in the form input.

```
if (empty($_POST["feedtitle"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $feedtitleErr = "Enter feed title";
} elseif (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/i',$_POST["feedtitle"])) {
    $has_errors = false;
    $feedtitleErr = "Enter text only";
} else {
    $feedtitle = validate_input($_POST["feedtitle"]);
}
```

When created the form this works fine. When editing the form data however is the input is left empty the empty field error "Enter feed title" does not fire and if I enter anything other than letters e.g. numbers no value is passed i.e. the variable $feedtitle is blank. If I enter text however it saves.

I don't think the query is the issue.

```
$Query = "UPDATE ccregisterfeed SET author='$author', category='$category',
copyright='$copyright', feeddescription='$feeddescription', feedtitle='$feedtitle',
websitelink='$websitelink', imagelink='$imagelink', imagetitle='$imagetitle',
subtitle='$subtitle' WHERE id='$feedid' AND username ='$user'";
```

FULL SCRIPT

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
require "authenticate.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$message = $_GET['message'];
$user = $_SESSION['UserName'];

//declare form field and form field error variables
$authorErr = $categoryErr = $copyrightErr = $feeddescriptionErr = $feedlinkErr = $feedtitleErr = $websitelinkErr = $imagelinkErr = $imagetitleErr = $subtitleErr = "";
$author = $category = $copyright = $feeddescription = $feedlink = $feedtitle = $websitelink = $imagelink = $imagetitle = $subtitle = "";

//form field validation
function validate_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$has_errors = false;
if (empty($_POST["author"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$authorErr = "Enter your name";
}else{
$author = validate_input($_POST["author"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["category"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$categoryErr = "Enter a category";
}else {
$category = validate_input($_POST["category"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["copyright"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$copyrightErr = "Enter copyright details";
} else {
$copyright = validate_input($_POST["copyright"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["feeddescription"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$feeddescriptionErr = "Enter feed description";
} else {
$feeddescription = validate_input($_POST["feeddescription"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["feedtitle"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$feedtitleErr = "Enter feed title";
} elseif (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/i',$_POST["feedtitle"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$feedtitleErr = "Enter text only";
} else {
$feedtitle = validate_input($_POST["feedtitle"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["websitelink"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$websitelinkErr = "Enter link to website";
} else {
$websitelink = validate_input($_POST["websitelink"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["imagelink"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$imagelinkErr = "Enter link to image";
} else {
$imagelink = validate_input($_POST["imagelink"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["imagetitle"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$imagetitleErr = "Enter image name";
} else {
$imagetitle = validate_input($_POST["imagetitle"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["subtitle"])) {
$has_errors = true;
$subtitleErr = "Enter feed subtitle";
} else {
$subtitle = validate_input($_POST["subtitle"]);
}

// var_dump ($date);
// var_dump ($feedlink);
// var_dump ($feeddescription);

//write edited data into tables matching logged in user with their data
$feedid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['feedid']);

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$feeddescription = str_replace("_", "", $feeddescription);
$feeddescription = str_replace("-", "", $feeddescription);
$feeddescription = str_replace("!", "", $feeddescription);
$feeddescription = str_replace("#", "", $feeddescription);
$feeddescription = str_replace("'", "", $feeddescription);

$Query = "UPDATE ccregisterfeed SET author='$author', category='$category', copyright='$copyright', feeddescription='$feeddescription', feedtitle='$feedtitle', websitelink='$websitelink', imagelink='$imagelink', imagetitle='$imagetitle', subtitle='$subtitle' WHERE id='$feedid' AND username ='$user'";

if($sql = mysql_query($Query)) {
header("location: rss.php");
// header("location: feededit.php");
} else {
die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error());
}
}

//show logged in user their updated data
$user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccregisterfeed WHERE username = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$id=$row['id'];
$author = $row['author'];
$category = $row['category'];
$copyright = $row['copyright'];
$feeddescription = $row['feeddescription'];
$feedtitle = $row['feedtitle'];
$websitelink = $row['websitelink'];
$imagelink = $row['imagelink'];
$imagetitle = $row['imagetitle'];
$subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
}

//delete form and image data when users clicks delete button
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])){
$deleteuser = $_POST['Delete'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM ccregisterfeed WHERE id = '$deleteuser'");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE ccregisterfeed AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
$message = 'Feed Deleted';
header("Location: feededit.php?&message=".urlencode($message));
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<form action="feededit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="edit" id="editfeed">

<fieldset>
<div class="legendcreate">Feed Edit</div>

<div class="feedcontainer">
<div class="feedcontainerinner">

<div><label class="labelshow">Author</label><input id="author" class="insetfeed" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Author" value="<?PHP print $author ; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $authorErr;?></p></div>

<?php if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($message)): ?>
<div class="messagebox">
<?php echo $message ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div><label class="labelshow">Category</label><input id="category" class="insetfeed" name="category" type="text" placeholder="Category" value="<?PHP print $category; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $categoryErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Copyright</label><input id="copyright" class="insetfeed" name="copyright" type="text" placeholder="Copyright" value="<?PHP print $copyright; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $copyrightErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Feed Title</label><input id="feedtitle" class="insetfeed" name="feedtitle" type="text" placeholder="Feed Title" value="<?PHP print $feedtitle; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $feedtitleErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Website Link</label><input id="websitelink" class="insetfeed" name="websitelink" type="text" placeholder="Website Link" value="<?PHP print $websitelink; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $websitelinkErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Image Link</label><input id="imagelink" class="insetfeed" name="imagelink" type="text" placeholder="Image Link" value="<?PHP print $imagelink; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $imagelinkErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Image Title</label><input id="imagetitle" class="insetfeed" name="imagetitle" type="text" placeholder="Image Title" value="<?PHP print $imagetitle; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $imagetitleErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelshow">Subtitle</label><input id="subtitle" class="insetfeed" name="subtitle" type="text" placeholder="Subtitle" value="<?PHP print $subtitle; ?>"/><p class="errorinput"><?php echo $subtitleErr;?></p></div>

<div><textarea id="description" name="feeddescription" class="textareadescription" placeholder="Enter feed description"><?php
    $out = htmlspecialchars_decode($feeddescription); 
    $out = str_replace( '\n', '<br />', $out ); 
    echo $out; 
    ?></textarea>

<div class="submit"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Save"/></div>
<div class="delete"><input name="deletebtn" type="submit" class="resetbtn" value="Delete"/></div>

<input type="hidden" name="feedid" value="<?phpecho $id;?>"/>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why do you write `$has_errors = false;` after the `preg_match` since it is an error too *(if I understand well)*? Note that the i modifier is redundant.

Comment: I was debugging. It changed it back to true. Same problem. The modifier is redundant?

Comment: are you sure that `validate_input` returns the string in case of success? What returns  `var_dump(validate_input($_POST["feedtitle"]));` in the `else` part.

Comment: Yes var_dump returns the value entered in the form input. I use the same query when creating the record but it doesn't work on update. I think it's related to the fetch array that displays the data back to the user. I've added it to the script.

Comment: You're assigning `$has_errors` but you never test it?

Comment: I test it by leaving the input empty and by adding numbers. I think I'll have to use str_replace instead of preg_match in this case.